# How to make it possible to add more than one form for a user

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble creating a model for user availability

I already have something like this

models.py

```
class Availability(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    starting_hour = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True)
    ending_hour = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

When a user tries to add an availability for another day of the week, a message appears that the availability for that user already exists
I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You have a One to One relation between User and Availability, change it to a foreign key:

```
class Availability(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    starting_hour = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True)
    ending_hour = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

A One to One relation means that there can only be one object of User for Availability and vice-versa. Making this change may also make it such that getting availability objects would now be different, previously this would have been fine `user.availability` now you would need `user.availability_set.all()`